# Can I sign a Active Directory user into a SharePoint site automatically from another website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, authentication, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET website which users log into etc., and also a SharePoint site. The SharePoint site authenticates users using Active Directory. For each user in the ASP.NET website we are planning to create (the first time they log in) and store a corresponding Active Directory account/username.

Once the user is signed in to the ASP.NET website, is there any way that we can send them to the SharePoint site without them having to log in?

I am looking at creating a Trusted Login Provider using the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955607.aspx - when a user tries to access the sharepoint site they would:

- Choose the login type (either Windows Authentication or the CustomSTS)
- If choosing CustomSTS, be sent to a Security Token Service within the ASP.NET web site
- ASP.NET web site would authenticate the user (if not already logged in) and send the user back to SharePoint, passing the user's Name and WindowsUserName claims

It looks like this should work, and this is what I am trying to do, but I am concerned that using this method the user will only be known to SharePoint as a user within the Custom STS, and not the Active Directory. The SharePoint site will contain Analysis Services stuff which for which we need the user to be authenticated against AD, not just custom STS, so will this not work?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. It may be that there is a completely different and better way to approach this problem.

Comment: Did you considered forms authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help? I already have the user authenticated on the asp.net site, and I want to authenticate them against AD. The two accounts are different.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different factors here. You need to make sure your kerberos is setup properly if you are using kerb on the Sharepoint Site. So checking SPNs, and what not, but also look into using claims based auth that creates a token for the user.